# python 2.7: round a float up to next even number

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I would like to round up a float to the next even number.

Steps:

1) check if a number is odd or even

2) if odd, round up to next even number

I have step 1 ready, a function which checks if a give number is even or not:

```
def is_even(num):
    if int(float(num) * 10) % 2 == 0:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

but I'm struggling with step 2....

Any advice?

Note: all floats will be positive.

Comment: But why your function's name is `is_even`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no need for step 1. Just divide the value by 2, round up to the nearest integer, then multiply by 2 again:

```
import math

def round_up_to_even(f):
    return math.ceil(f / 2.) * 2
```

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> def round_up_to_even(f):
...     return math.ceil(f / 2.) * 2
... 
>>> round_up_to_even(1.25)
2
>>> round_up_to_even(3)
4
>>> round_up_to_even(2.25)
4
```

Comment: gives `2.0` and `4.0` etc. i think this changed in python 3 vs 2

Comment: @deweydb yes, you are correct. Python 3 changed the returned type for `math.ceil()`; in Python 2 it returns a float with integral value, in Python 3 an int is returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 3.5654
b = 2.568

a = int(a) if ((int(a) % 2) == 0) else int(a) + 1
b = int(b) if ((int(b) % 2) == 0) else int(b) + 1

print a
print b
```

value of a after execution

```
a = 4
```

value of b after execution

```
b = 2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I think it is quite obvious why this answer the problem and I like the simplicity of it, upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

def round_to_ceil_even(f):
  if (math.floor(f)%2 == 0): 
    return math.floor(f)
  else: 
    return math.floor(f)+1
```

[image]

```
def round_to_ceil_even(f):
  if (math.floor(f)%2 == 0): 
    return int(f)
  else: 
    return int(f+1)
```

Comment: What do you think `round_to_ceil_even(2.3)` should give? Right now, your function  simply returns `2.3`, which is definitely not an "even number". What about an input of `3.3`? (Your function gives `4.3` as an output. I doubt that's what the OP wanted.)

Comment: Function updated.