# Round a float UP to next odd integer

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

How can I round a float **up** to the **next** odd integer? I found how it can be done for even numbers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361757/python-2-7-round-a-float-up-to-next-even-number). So I tried something like:

```
import numpy as np

def round_up_to_odd(f):
    return np.ceil(f / 2.) * 2 + 1
```

But of course this does not round it to the NEXT odd number:

```
>>> odd(32.6)
35.0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `+ 1` to `- 1`?

Comment: Problem would then be: round_up_to_odd(2) => 1.0 but I need to round it UP

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to `ceil` before dividing:

```
import numpy as np

def round_up_to_odd(f):
    return np.ceil(f) // 2 * 2 + 1
```

Comment: sys.version gives me '2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]' but only the first code works?!

Comment: @a.smiet I misplaced a bracket in the second example, actually the first one should also works in python 2+ since `//` already truncates float division in python 2.

Answer (score 8):

What about:

```
def round_up_to_odd(f):
    f = int(np.ceil(f))
    return f + 1 if f % 2 == 0 else f
```

The idea is first to round up to an integer and then check if the integer is odd or even.