# Rounding down numbers to the nearest even number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of numbers that look like this:

```
data = [291.79, 499.31, 810.93, 1164.25]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Onset'])
```

Is there an elegant way to round **down** the odd numbers to the nearest even number? The even numbers should be rounded to the nearest even integer. This should be the output:

```
data = [290, 498, 810, 1164]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Onset'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python 2.7: round a float up to next even number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361757/python-2-7-round-a-float-up-to-next-even-number)

Comment: But note for the above, change the return to  `return math.floor(f / 2.) * 2` (as you want to round down not up).

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal except for the small difference that this asks for `floor(x / 2) * 2` rather than `ceil(x / 2) * 2`

Comment: @Luatic yep but that should be easy to figure out by the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use modulo operator:

```py
df['Onset_new'] = (i:=df['Onset'].astype(int)) - i % 2
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Onset  Onset_new
0   291.79        290
1   499.31        498
2   810.93        810
3  1164.25       1164
```

Comment: Great, thanks! What if I want to save the output as a new column in the dataframe instead of overriding the initial one?

Comment: In `i % 2 != 0` the `!= 0` is redundant.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yup, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Plenty of ways. One way could be halving a number, then using floor division, and then doubling it. This can be done in the traditional way:

```py
def round_down_even(n):
    return 2 * int(n // 2)
```

Then just use

```py
df["Onset"] = df["Onset"].apply(round_down_even)
```

or as mozway points out, a more efficient way is

```py
df['Onset'] = df['Onset'].floordiv(2).mul(2)
```

(Approx 20% faster, as well as more clean)

Comment: The vectorial equivalent (more efficient) would be `df['Onset'].floordiv(2).mul(2)` ;)

Comment: That's better. I like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.apply(lambda x:np.floor(x)-np.floor(x)%2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant way ([one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program)) to achieve this using the popular [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library. You can make use of the `numpy.floor` and `numpy.ceil` functions to round down and up, respectively.
The code to round the data would be *(using techniques like [integer division](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-double-slash-operator-floor-division/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20we%20can%20perform,floor()%20function.))*:

```py
rounded_data = np.where(np.mod(np.floor(data), 2) == 1, np.floor(data) // 2 * 2, np.ceil(data) // 2 * 2)
```

Remember that the line `import numpy as np` is necessary.

The output of `rounded_data` after data frame:

```py
dfRounded = pd.DataFrame(rounded_data, columns=['Onset'])

print(dfRounded)
```

is:

```
    Onset
0   290.0
1   498.0
2   810.0
3  1164.0
```

Finally, if you want to convert the values to [integers](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_numbers.asp) you can use:

```py
dfRounded['Onset'] = dfRounded['Onset'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function that rounds to the nearest even (with `math.floor`) and then applying it to your data frame:

```py
   def even_round_down(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return np.floor(number)
    else:
        return np.floor(number / 2) * 2
```

You can do:

```
df['Onset'] = df['Onset'].apply(even_round_down)
```

Comment: Gives incorrect results. For example `even_round_down(0.5)` returns `-2`.

Comment: @juanpethes Well, in that case, you can add a check that if the number is < 1 then the result should be 0. I was assuming positive numbers above 1.

Comment: Still doesn't work. For example `even_round_down(2.5)` returns `0`.

Comment: @juanpethes your right fixed

Comment: The test is not really needed, `np.floor(number / 2) * 2` or `number//2*2` is sufficient